# How to change "div" place in the flow?

Tags: html, css

There are two columns (left and right) with float positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/GBa4r/

```
<style>
    .container {width:200px;}
    .right {float: right; width: 30%;}
    .left {float: left; width: 70%;}​
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">2</div>
    <div class="left">1</div>
</div>
```

​
For print styles I need to change column places like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/GBa4r/1/ (".left" column above ".right")

What css code I should use in

```
   <link href="/css/print.css" media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to do it without change html code?

Comment: You use a print stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS @media queries

```
@media print {
  /*Styles goes here*/
}
```

Or use a print specific stylesheet using `media="print"`

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print_specific_sheet.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a specific print stylesheet. You can do it with the `media` attribute on the `link` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Or you could do so from inside of the CSS file:

```
@media print {
    /* print specific styles */
}
```

Comment: LOL what makes this different from my answer

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Nothing, I didn't see your answer when I posted this. +1 to you.

Comment: I mean what css code I should use in print.css, to change it =)

Comment: @JuliaKotova Whatever styles you want in printing, just define those styles inside media query or a different stylesheet using `media="print"`

Comment: @JuliaKotova: You put the styles that makes it look like what you want. Overwrite the float (`float: none;`) to remove the float, and make adjustments so it looks the way you want it to.

Comment: Please read question one more time =) As answer I need CSS code to put it in my print.css =))

Answer (score 0):

A print stylesheet works in much the same way as a regular stylesheet, except it only gets called up when the page is printed. To make it work, the following needs to be inserted into the top of every web page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The file, print.css is the print stylesheet, and the media="print" command means that this CSS file only gets called up when web pages are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS.

```
.container {width:200px;}
.right {background-color: #eaeaea; width: 30%;position: absolute;
top: 18px;}
.left {background-color: #ccc; width: 70%; position: absolute;
top: 0%;}​
```

Comment: Height of the upper (".left") column should be flexible, because it depends from a content inside. So style ".right {top: 18px}" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/GBa4r/5/

Add to parent container:

```
display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
```

remove from children:

```
.right {float: right;}
.left {float: left;}
```

This was horizontal change.

If positioning is to be changed vertically as in,
http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/GBa4r/6/

then, add

```
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
```

to parent.